# Connect to RDS AWS db using SSH key from java

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, entitymanager

I have a java application that is deployed on AWS EC2 instance. This application is connecting to an AWS RDS db. This works fine. But from my local windows when I debug the code in intellij, it is not able to connect to db because it require an ssh key and EC2 instance ip for connection along with password.
Java application uses oracle hibernate connection with entity manager.
I came across this solution
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connectivity-problems.html#step-4-check-if-the-connection-with-ssh-ssl
but I don't see SSH configuration option on Tool windows in my Intellij.

Could someone help me on how can I make db connection using java application using intellij or by deploying application in tomcat in my local?

Comment: You need to connect through SSH tunnel. Your EC2 is in fact ssh tunnel to AWS RDS db. See https://i.imgur.com/eu6Jj03.png

Comment: Is this options available in intellij community edition? I don't see it there

Comment: No, only in Ultimate. See https://i.imgur.com/g3piHYZ.png
No you can use Ultimate for free by downloading [EAP version of IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/)